# My app is getting a very high percentage of in app purchases failing due to "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" in the released version of the app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I added in app purchase to my app and everything works great when I tested it in the sandbox.  The app is currently in production and users are successfully making in app purchases as I can see the data in the sales report in iTunes Connect.  In my app I track when a user starts the process to do an in app purchase and then if it was successful or not.  72% of the time that a user starts an in app purchases it fails with the error "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".  My app has enough users making purchases that this is in not due to a small sample set, (i.e. 3 of the 4 users who did an IAP failed).  While I have a decent amount of user's successfully making purchases, 72% seems very high to fail with "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

Does anyone know what can cause this error in production?  Is there something I am doing wrong in my app or can I give a better error message to users so that they know what is going on?  When I searched stack overflow for this question I found a lot of posts about this error in the sandbox or happening on EVERY purchase, but I did not find any posts about when this happens sometimes in production.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I'd highly recommend contacting Apple's developer support. You get at least one direct support instance per year, and since this is directly impacting your revenue, it would seem like a good time to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the user initiates and then cancels a purchase.

Because the text in the `NSLocalizedDescription` of the `NSError` is not very helpful, I show my own error message instead.

Comment: Do you by chance know if this is ALWAYS the error when they cancel or just usually the error message?

Comment: It can happen in other cases as well. For example when the user is in a store that you do not sell in. E.g. Japanese user trying to buy when you are only setup for the US store.